# Split result in to Strings

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using a google function to return the Long/lat of a location based on an address, however when I try to split it out the results come back as undefined (it works if i alert `results[0].geometry.latitude` out) - but myLatLong does not get set

function getLatLong(address){
    var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;

```
geo.geocode({'address':address},function(results, status){
    var myLatLong;
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        myLatLong = results[0].geometry.latitude;
        localStorage.setItem("SearchLat", myLatLong.split("," ,0));
        localStorage.setItem("SearchLong", myLatLong.split("," ,1));

    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }

});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geometry.location` is an object, not a string.  From the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResults):

> location contains the geocoded latitude,longitude value. Note that we return this location as a [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLng) object, not as a formatted string.

I think you need:

```
myLatLong = results[0].geometry.location;
localStorage.setItem("SearchLat", myLatLong.lat());
localStorage.setItem("SearchLong", myLatLong.lng());
```

Note that you can also convert a LatLng object to a string "lat,lng" using `toUrlValue`, so I guess you could also use this:

```
var myLatLong = results[0].geometry.location.toUrlValue();
localStorage.setItem("SearchLat", myLatLong .split(",")[0]);
localStorage.setItem("SearchLong", myLatLong.split(",")[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that makes perfect sense! What's the best way of waiting for that to finish before moving on? The first time they are null and the second time they are not